# How to disable a textbar in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VSC and since three or four days, always when I type "r" in css files, yes only css files, a weird textbox will open. e.g. if I wanna write "margin", I'll killed at r, my cursor will be moved into the box and in the textbox then contains "ma". sth like this: https://ibb.co/fdbFtBn if I continue, in the line is "ma" and in the box is "gin".

[image: here is the moment, where i pressed r]

[image: here is the moment, where i continued writing]

Is this at all from VSC? Or is this a extension from me? If it is a extension, sorry for this question.

I have already googled this problem, but I found nothing that was helpfull. And on VSC's page is: "You can ask questions and search for answers on Stack Overflow"

I hope someone can help me here.

Thanks for every usefull help.

Comment: That's strange. Open Cog > Keyboard Shortcuts, click "Record keys" button (first on right in input field) and press "r": it may reveal some command for 'css' editor.langId context you can hopefully unbind.  I don't recognize such inline input field you pictured, though.

Comment: thanks for your help :D I resetted `keybindings.editor.recordSearchKeys` in the Keyboard Shortcuts. And now i can write without problems thanks! @myf

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Still, it is even more strange, because this command is (coincidentally) exactly what that "Record keys" button does. For curiosity, I tried to bind it to "r" with clean "when" condition and it (quite expectably) disabled the "r" key. But that floating input field remains mystery for me (it was not generated in my setup)…